# What is the value of the ratio of BS and RQ segments in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference: What is the value of the ratio of $BS$ and $RQ$ segments in the figure below where $SD=2AR$?

[image]

My progress:

I tried to draw some auxiliary lines...some triangle similarities appear ..$CDF$ and $APR$, $PQJ$ and $PCI$, $SQ =\frac{CF}{2}$, $QJ$ = $ \frac{CI}{2}$...but I didn't find the main relation

[image]

Comment: Hello, is $ABCD$ a rhombus or a parallelogram or any quadrilateral? Part of your question is not in English and is hard to follow.

Comment: @MathLover,,sorry ..already corrected for english

Comment: @MathLover...nothing is said about the type of quadrilateral

Comment: If $BC$ is not parallel to $AD$, I do not think we can state length of $AD$ and $BC$ in terms of $AR$ as we cannot say $\triangle APR \sim \triangle DCF$. To me the question seems incomplete as written unless we make assumptions based on the diagram.

Comment: @MathLover..i agree with you..The way you are I got the answer approximately 1.5...but the book options are $\frac{4}{5}, \frac{5}{4}, \frac{6}{5}, \frac {5}{6} and 1(answer)$

Comment: I can'y find point $I$ in your pictures. Do you mean $G$?

Comment: @MathLover  The Angle was updated in the newest version of the book and is now considered to be a parallelogram..I already corrected my figure

Comment: @ACB..you're right..I = G...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

With Andrei's data:

$\measuredangle \frac{57}{2} \rightarrow proportion \frac{1}{2}\\
MB = 4x, MS = 3x \rightarrow \triangle MBS: \boxed{BS^2 = (4x)^2+(3x)^2}(I)\\
\triangle RQS: \boxed{RQ^2 = (4x^2)+(3x^2}(II)\\
\therefore \frac{I}{II} = \color{red}1$}

Comment: So much easier if you write the correct problem statement :)

Comment: @Andrei...sure...but the problem was in the book and not how I transcribed it...I managed to find a newer edition of the book where they corrected the statement

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $AR=x$ and $BC=y$. Then you know $SD=2x$. $PG$ line is at half height, so from similarity of $\triangle APR$ and $\triangle DCF$ you get $DF=2x$. In trapeze $RPCF$ you have $PQ=QC$, so you will get $RS=SF=4x$. It's easy to show that $RF=y+x$ (draw the perpendicular from $B$ to $AD$). Then $$RS+SD+DF=4x+2x+2x=8x=y+x$$
Therefore $y=7x$. What you want is $$\frac{BC}{RS}=\frac{y}{4x}=\frac74$$

**EDIT**
With new updated text of the question, we need the $BS/RQ$ ratio. For that, we are going to use Pythagoras' theorem, and the fact that $\tan 26.5^\circ\approx 1/2$.
$$MS=AD-AM-SD=y-2x-2x=7x-4x=3x\\RS=RM+MS=x+3x=4x$$
In $\triangle PAR$ from the tangent you get $$\tan26.5^\circ=\frac12=\frac{x}{PR}$$So $PR=2x$. Then $BM=4x$. Due to triangle similarity, $$QJ=\frac{CG}2=\frac{2x}2=x$$
Therefore $QS=3$x.
Now$$\frac{BS}{QR}=\frac{\sqrt{BM^2+MS^2}}{\sqrt{RS^2+QS^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(4x)^2+(3x)^2}{(4x)^2+(3x)^2}}=1$$

Comment: ..thousand pardons ..but the correct one would be $\frac{BS}{RQ}$...

excellent resolution

Comment: In that case you start from the same way. You just need to use $\sin 17.5^\circ\approx 0.3$. Draw the perpendicular from $B$ to $AB$, say point $M$. Then $AM=2x$. And you get $BM=h$ from the tangent. It's easy to show $QS=\frac 34 h$. Then use Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: the answer book: $\frac{BS}{RQ}$ = 1

Comment: I'll try..thanks..as it is a specific geometry book, I believe that trigonometry is not used..

Comment: Note that at some point you need to know something about triangles with angle $18.5^\circ$. Sorry about the 17.5 above. The tangent of that angle is about $1/3$, so $AR/PR=1/3$. If you don't specify the angle, you can move $BC$ straight up and down, and the points on the $AF$ line will not move. Your $BS$ and $RQ$ lines depend on the points on the horizontal axis and on the length of $PR$.

Comment: http://www.gogeometry.com/school-college/p849-special-right-triangle-catheti-ratio-1-3-angle-18.5-degrees.htm

Comment: ,,,interesting this relation of 1/3,,, I have updated the drawing with your considerations,,, I think that all that is left is to find SD as a function of x

Comment: You are given that $SD=2AR=2x$

Comment: ...sorry ..not SD but SM,,..SM = 3x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128916/discussion-between-peta-arantes-and-andrei).

Comment: With updated data, now the problem has a correct solution

Comment: ...Could you update your answer so I can accept it and mark it?

Comment: Done.  Glad I could be of help

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few well known right angled triangles -

- $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle with angles as $37^\circ$ and $53^\circ$
- $1$-$2$-$\sqrt5$ triangle with one of the angles as $\frac{53^\circ}{2}$, where perpendicular sides are in ratio $1:2$
- $1$-$3$-$\sqrt{10}$ triangle with one of the angles as $\frac{37^\circ}{2}$, where perpendicular sides are in ratio $1:3$

Please note that you can easily get last two from the first and hence remembering first always helps.

So in $\triangle APR$, $PR = 2 AR = 2x$ and as both sides of $\triangle RSQ$ and $\triangle BMS$ are same, they are congruent.

$\therefore RQ = BS$